# How do you display a keyboard using Trigger.io on iOS without requiring user action?

Tags: ios, keyboard, trigger.io

I would like a **keyboard to be automatically displayed** when I call $('#elementId').focus() on an input text box. Is there anyway to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just using .focus() on an element is restricted due to browser security limitations. However, you could write a [Trigger.io native plugin](https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/native_plugins/index.html) that disables this limitation for iOS 6 and above. I actually use this for an app already and want to release it on GitHub soon. For now, this should get you going:

```
NSString *reqSysVer = @"6.0";
NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];

// check if we are on >= iOS 6
if ([currSysVer compare:reqSysVer options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending) {
    [ForgeApp sharedApp].webView.keyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction = NO;
    [task success:nil];
}
else {
    [task error:@"Invalid iOS version"];
}
```

After you called the plugin method once in your app, you will be able to use the normal .focus() on an input element.

Comment: Please release on GitHub soon.  Thanks for your help!